# Download RSS feed as xml file from Sharepoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, xml

How it is possible to download xml file out of this feed (website) using PowerShell?

I can authenticate with sharepoint using CSOM but do not what to do next.
As service user is not administrator I cannot use "SPOService".

This script works OK for standard website, but not for Sharepoint.

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load("http://www.{company}/feed/")
$doc.save("C:\temp\feed.xml")
```

I am getting this error when using for company Sharepoint:

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Thanks for your time considering this question.

Answer (score 3):

The error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

occurs since authentication is required for this operation in SharePoint Online. You could utilize [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) from CSOM API for that purpose.

The following example demonstrates how to download RSS feed from SharePoint Online and save it into file.

**Complete example**

> Prerequisites: [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

Function Download-Content([string]$Url,[System.Net.ICredentials]$Credentials)
{
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $client.Credentials = $Credentials
    $client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    $content = $client.DownloadString($url)
    $client.Dispose()
    return $content
}



$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$WebUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
$ListId = "{65CDF954-5169-47B6-9014-0151D2083821}"
#Retrieve List RSS
$listRssUrl = "$WebUrl/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=$ListId"
$credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
[xml]$rss = Download-Content -Url $listRssUrl  -Credentials $credentials
#save
$rss.save("c:\temp\feed.xml")
```